# Compare overall overlap with multiple ranges

Tags: r, algorithm

Here is my dataframe

```
df = structure(list(A1 = c("0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", 
"0.01"), A2 = c("0.01", "0.18", "0.31", "0.06", "1.71", "0.01"
), B1 = c("0.62", "3.68", "9.68", "1.70", "0.02", "0.01"), B2 = c("20.00", 
"20.00", "20.00", "20.00", "0.02", "20"), C1 = c("0.02", "5", 
"0.16", "0.01", "0.03", "0.01"), C2 = c("20.00", "20.00", "20.00", 
"20.00", "20.00", "20.00"), Min = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02), Max = c(0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24)), .Names = c("A1", 
"A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2", "Min", "Max"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

- `A1`-`A2` defines first range
- `B1`-`B2` defines second range
- `C1`-`C2` defines third range
- `Min`-`Max` defines the main range

I need to compare `A1-A2`, `B1-B2`, `C1-C2` together against `Min-Max`.
If there is a hole, then assign 0. If there is no hole assign 1.

For example in the second row, between 0.18 and 0.24 (`Max` for 2nd row), neither `A1-A2`, `B1-B2`, or `C1-C2` overlap with `Min-Max`. Therefore assign 0. I would also like to extract 0.18 and 0.24 if possible. For all other rows assign 1. The values can be extracted to a vector or a new column.

Here's a figure to explain what I mean by hole in the range.

[image]

`A2 >= A1`, `B2 >= B1`, `C2 >= C1`, and `Max >= Min` is always `TRUE`

Comment: what is the definition of hole? confused about why you considered `A2`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The second row I see has `Min` = 0.02 and `Max` = 0.24 while the ranges goes up to 20.

Comment: @d.b in the second row, how is `A1-A2` covering the Min-Max and not others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library for that

```
library(intervals)

d <- sapply(df,as.numeric)
A <- Intervals(d[,1:2])
B <- Intervals(d[,3:4])
C <- Intervals(d[,5:6])
M <- Intervals(d[,7:8])

lapply(1:nrow(d),function(n) {
  interval_difference(M[n], interval_union(A[n],B[n],C[n]))
})
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
Object of class Intervals_full
0 intervals over R:


[[2]]
Object of class Intervals_full
1 interval over R:
(0.18, 0.24]

[[3]]
Object of class Intervals_full
0 intervals over R:


[[4]]
Object of class Intervals_full
0 intervals over R:


[[5]]
Object of class Intervals_full
0 intervals over R:


[[6]]
Object of class Intervals_full
0 intervals over R:
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest case is that A1<=A2, B1<=B2, and C1<=C2.  If that is not the case then you should go through and fix that first.

Now if you look at your pictures, one (or more) of A1, B1, and C1 must be <= Min and one (or more) of A2, B2, and C2 must be >= Max.  If not then you have a hole at one of the ends.  Now for the end points that are between Min and Max, they have to be inside of at least one of the other intervals (or equal to a boundary point of another interval) or there will be a gap, e.g. A2 must be between B1 and B2 or between C1 and C2.  The same for all points between Min and Max.

So just go through your 6 boundary points and check A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, and C2 to see if they are below Min, above Max, or inside of the other 2 bounds.
Then check the special cases that all three of A1, B1, and C1 are greater than Max or all three of A2, B2, and C2 are less than Min.  If all the above conditions hold (and at least one interval covers Min and Max) then there are no holes.  Otherwise there is a hole.

You can test the above with a bunch of if-then statements.  I can't think of anything more efficient right off (but someone else may).